# Update Cache with one item C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I am getting users and their data from external webservice. I cache those items because I don't want to hit web service every time. Now, If user update any of their information, I am saving it through webservice. But I don't want to get the latest data from web service as it takes lot of time. Instead I want to update my cache. Can I do that ? If so, what would be the best way ? Here is my Code

```
List<User> users = appSecurity.SelectUsers();
var CacheKey = string.Format("GetUserList_{0}", currentUser);
CacheFactory.AddCacheItem(CacheKey, users, 300);
```

CacheFactory is a class where I handle Adding, Clearing and Removing cache. Below is the code

```
 public static void RemoveCacheItem(string key)
    {
        Cache.Remove(key);
    }

public static void ClearCache()
    {
        System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = Cache.GetEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            RemoveCacheItem(enumerator.Key.ToString());
        }
    }
  public static void AddCacheItem<T>(string key, T value, double timeOutInSeconds)
    {
        var Item = GetCacheItem<T>(key);
        if (Item != null)
        {
            RemoveCacheItem(key);
            Item = value;
        }
        Cache.Insert(key, value, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(timeOutInSeconds), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
    }
```

Comment: This isn't a question about a problem.  "What would be the best way?" is to much of an open question and is basically impossible to answer.  Do you have a specific problem you want solved?

Comment: What is that `CacheFactory`? It doesn't seem to be the standard one...

Comment: @Hogan I am sorry, Ignore the best way. How can I update my cache ?

Comment: What are you using for cache?  we would need to know the details and an example of what you tried that did not work and what happened.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi CacheFactory is my class where I handle all the caching code like adding, clear and removing cache.

Comment: @Hogan Web.caching namespace

Comment: If you want useful help you are going to have to tell me more than a .NET namespace.  I can't read minds (not yet).

Comment: Attempt to read your mind:  if you are using `web.caching.cache` object.  Use the remove function and the add function to update.

Comment: @Hogan Updated the above code with my CacheFactory class

Comment: That code is not complete, `Cache` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, it can be done. It can also be done in many different ways depending on what you want to solve. At the basic level you can create a cache by using a `List<T>` or `Dictionary<T,T>` to store your data.

When you get information from the external web-service, you push the data into your List or Dictionary. You can then use that data throughout your application. When you need to update that cache, you update the value in the List/Dictionary.

You can update your dictonary like so

```
Dictionary<string, int> list = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

then you can set the value for the key "test" as follows

```
list["test"] = list["test"] + 1;
```

When you are ready to push the updated data to the external source. All you need to do is properly parse that data into the format the source is expecting and send away.

Like I said there are many different ways to do this, but this is a basic sample way to accomplishing it. You can use this example to build off and go from there.

Comment: "When you need to update that cache, you update the value in the List/Dictionary." - How can I do this ?

Comment: Do I need to write Update method in CacheFactory ?

Comment: You would want to create an update method for your CacheFactory. Where you lookup in your cache object and update the object.